# When do we need the *.meta.js files in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

It says in the docs: "In addition, each of these also have a corresponding {file}.meta.js meta file which will be used for reflection and other functionality."

Q1: does this mean we only need to include these files if we are using reflection?

Q2: what is the "other functionality"?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the docs are wrong. This file is not used for reflection. It is used by the compiler and useful should you need to distribute your kotlin code as a library.